# VisualStudioCommunity2017 C2131_Problem

Tags: c++

this code is a working c++ code but, in visual studio community 2017 I face that error and I don't know why? Notice that this code is running on Codeblocks IDE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int prefix_pair[200000];

int main()
{
    int n, max_N = 0;
    long long sum = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int Data[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> Data[i];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = (i+1); j < n; j++)
        {

            sum = Data[j] + Data[i];
            prefix_pair[sum] += 1;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        if (max_N < prefix_pair[i])
            max_N = prefix_pair[i];

    cout << max_N << endl;
}
```

Error Message in picture [error message I think it is a compiler issue but, how to solve it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DakAO.png)

also notice that this code is a solution to this problem on
[codeforces](https://codeforces.com/group/T3p02rhrmb/contest/338055/problem/A)

Comment: Variable length arrays as that cin >> n;
    int Data[n]; is not a standard C++ feature. Instead use the standard container std::vector.

Comment: Too many people use one-and -only-one compiler and have no clue that the extensions in that compiler are not in fact part of the language. You will have similar problems porting Visual Studio code and tripping over the `_s` "safe" functions.